# Как через исключения получить имя метода и класса

Tags: c#

Как при возникновении исключения получить имя метода и класса в котором оно вызвано?

Comment: Exception.StackTrace, нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте свойство StackTrace, там расписано в плоть до номера строки.